# Multithreaded Java worker with a size restricted resource pool

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, worker

I have this 'Worker' class, which uses a resource 'Client'.
There may be any number of threads, running the 'Worker' at any given time.
The 'Client' is not thread-safe, thus I'm using 'ThreadLocal' for it.
The 'Client' connects to some server and executes a HTTP 'Request' that the worker feeds the 'Client'.

```
public class Worker {
// Client is NOT thread-safe !!! 
private static ThreadLocal<Client> client = new ThreadLocal<Client>();

@Override
protected void onGet(Request req) {
    handleRequest(req);
}

private void handleRequest(Request req) {
    someRunnableExecutor(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            get_client().send_req(req);
        }
    });
}

private Client get_client() {
    Client c = client.get();
    if (c == null) {
       c = new Client();
       client.set(c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

At the current implementation (above), stripped down for clarity, there are as many "active" 'Clients' as there are running 'Workers'.

This is a problem because the server is being exhausted.

What I can do is only fix the 'Worker'. Have no access to the 'Client', server or the executor that runs the workers.

What I want to do is to have a Queue of 'Client'(s) and a piece of a synchronized code, in the 'Worker', that takes a 'Client' off the Queue, if the Queue is empty the 'Worker' should wait till there is one in the Queue for him to take. Then put the 'Client' back into the Queue - synchronized as well.

I really want to keep it as simple as possible, with the possible minimum changes made to the code.

No new classes, no factories, just some data structure to hold the 'Client'(s) and synchronization.

I am a bit puzzled with how to achieve that generally, as well as by the fact that the 'Client' is not thread-safe and that I have to 'ThreadLocal'(ize) it. Is this how do I put that in a Queue?

```
private static Queue<ThreadLocal<CLient>> queue = 
      new LinkedList<ThreadLocal<CLient>>();
```

Also, how/where do I initialize that Queue, once, with say 5 clients?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Use a BlockingQueue or ConcurrentQueue for thread safe Queuing

Comment: Yes I'm confused why this is a problem.  Put your Client or some task (like the Worker) in a queue and just pull them out one at a time.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need ThreadLocal here, as you want to have less Clients than Workers. All you need in BlockingQueue. 
Notice! I supposed that Client's send_req is synchronous, if it's not - the code needs some changes in run() method

```
public class Worker {

    private static final int CLIENTS_NUMBER = 5;
    private static final BlockingQueue<Client> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(CLIENTS_NUMBER);

    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < CLIENTS_NUMBER; i++)
            queue.put(new Client());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onGet(Request req) {
        handleRequest(req);
    }

    private void handleRequest(Request req) {
        someRunnableExecutor(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Client client = takeClient();
                    client.send_req(req);
                    putClient(client);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Client takeClient() throws InterruptedException {
        return queue.take();
    }

    private void putClient(Client client) throws InterruptedException {
        queue.put(client);
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. I did not figure it out to start with, but all I needed here was a Queue implementations that is thread-safe. And yes, your assumption on send_req being synchronous is correct. Thank you for the extra mile of a code sample. I accepted your answer and voted it up but the vote up does not show cause I don't have a high enough reputation on stackoverflow.